# Why vsnwprintf missing

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, printf

I using `vsnprintf` for ansi string and it works well, returns `-1` only on error and returns count of needen size if it does not fit into buffer.
I need same function for wide strings, `vsnwprintf` just not exists. I also tried `_vsnwprintf`, but it acts really different, it returns -1 even if buffer too small, while I need to know how much to expand a buffer, but only when it's necessary, I don't want to make dummy calls just to determine needen size and only then expand a buffer.

If look at `vsnprintf` code:

```
int const _Result = __stdio_common_vsprintf(
    _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_PRINTF_OPTIONS | _CRT_INTERNAL_PRINTF_STANDARD_SNPRINTF_BEHAVIOR,
    _Buffer, _BufferCount, _Format, NULL, _ArgList);
return _Result < 0 ? -1 : _Result;
```

While _vsnwprintf approximately has:

```
int const _Result = __stdio_common_vswprintf(
    _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_PRINTF_OPTIONS | _CRT_INTERNAL_PRINTF_LEGACY_VSPRINTF_NULL_TERMINATION,
    _Buffer, _BufferCount, _Format, NULL, _ArgList);
return _Result < 0 ? -1 : _Result;
```

Looks like difference only in flags, I tried to call `__stdio_common_vswprintf` manually with `_CRT_INTERNAL_PRINTF_STANDARD_SNPRINTF_BEHAVIOR` flag, and it works exactly as I need, but also causing random crashes/freezes when application exiting. So I need `vsnwprintf` function, maybe someone know how to do it?

P.S. I using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wide character version of `vsnprintf` is called `vswprintf` (note: no `n`).  According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsprintf-vsprintf-l-vswprintf-vswprintf-l-vswprintf-l), it is compliant with ISO C so you can check the behaviour in the C Standard or [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfwprintf).

It is correct that it returns `-1` when the output would exceed the buffer size. There is no option to truncate output; you are supposed to make the "dummy call" to check buffer size.

You could always wrap a `vswprintf` call in another function that has the behaviour you desire (make the dummy call and then either truncate to fit, or return a malloc'd buffer). Be ware of truncating in the middle of a UTF-16 character.

---

Note that MSVC's `vsnprintf` changed its behaviour at some point (2015 maybe?) to be ISO C compliant; the original MSVC behaviour can be retrieved by calling `_vsnprintf`.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is ISO C standart return -1 on short buffer, or it's only a MSVC behaviour?

Comment: @StormgateStudio it could be any negative number, according to the standard

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_vsnwprintf()`.  Per [the documentation for `_vsnwprintf()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l) (note the leading underscore):

> ...
>
> ```
> int _vsnwprintf(
>    wchar_t *buffer,
>    size_t count,
>    const wchar_t *format,
>    va_list argptr
> );
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The value returned by all these functions does not include the
>   terminating null, whether one is written or not. **When `count` is zero,
>   the value returned is the number of characters the functions would
>   write, not including any terminating null. You can use this result to
>   allocate sufficient buffer space for the string and its terminating
>   null, and then call the function again to fill the buffer.**

Comment: Thank you for reply. As I said before I already tried _vsnwprintf function and it's returns -1 on short buffer, while I need same function as vsnprintf, but for wide characters.

Comment: @StormgateStudio Did you set `count` to zero first to find out how large a buffer you need?

Comment: I setting as count a size of buffer I have, and if function returns more that I have, then I reserving more and calling again with new buffer, it's working well with vsnprintf and usually from first call. But _vsnwprintf acts absolutely different